# What does the "Themes" service do in Windows 8?

Tags: windows, windows-8-preview, themes

I stopped the "Themes" service in Windows 8, but didn't notice anything.

What does it do?

Comment: What does its description say?

Answer (score 1):

In Windows 7 is it described as "Provides User Experience Theme Management"

I doubt it has changed in W8, try changing the theme with the service disabled, it will probably not work. Right click on desktop and select "personalize" to change the theme.

[According to this article](http://windows8themes.org/restarting-windows-8-themes-service.html) sometimes you will have trouble changing/applying new themes if the service is active, you have to restart the service to solve it, remember W8 is BETA software and will have tons of bugs.

Comment: Even less than a BETA... it's a Consumer Preview :) It's maked up Win 7. You can see a lot of legacy from this OS. A lot of things will move I bet, for a better coherence.

Comment: I think MS has moved away from "beta" nameplate, I doubt we will see anything released as W8 "beta", RC is next, then RTM, my 2 cents anyway.

Comment: See this...http://www.winsupersite.com/article/paul-thurrotts-wininfo/microsoft-deliver-nearfinal-windows-8-version-early-june-142913